# php Compare two large text files with each other displaying the difference

Tags: php, symfony

Does anyone have any good ways of comparing two large (9000+Lines) of files and highlighting the differences between the two?

The few things i found online seem to choke and die off when i throw in large files.

Comment: You want it server side i guess?! If so, `[jquery]` tag has no meaning here

Comment: Depending on your use case and if you are on linux yould could use the `diff` command on the files.

Comment: You can simply use xdiff_file_diff for comparing 2 text files and that can show the result in 3rd file. Check my answer.

Comment: you may go with [diff](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/diff) package

Comment: If you are on a Mac, `opendiff` (a.k.a. `FileMerge`) is superb. Use it like `opediff fileA fileB`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Text_Diff](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/download) pear package for comparing the difference between 2 text files.

There is also the [xdiff](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xdiff.php) extension available that you can use with [`xdiff_file_diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-file-diff.php) function like below:

```
xdiff_file_diff('old_file.txt', 'new_file.txt', 'diff.txt');
```

Where diff.txt would be the resulting file with the comparison between the two files.

Also you can use **xdiff_file_diff** function for comparing PHP files like below:

```
$old_version = 'my_script.php';
$new_version = 'my_new_script.php';

xdiff_file_diff($old_version, $new_version, 'my_script.diff', 2);
// above code makes unified diff of two php files with context length of 2.
```